# How to display how many time an array value is in the array?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I have an array which contains duplicate values. I need to display how many times each value is found in an array.

Let us say I have an array of 8 values, array = {1,2,3,1,1,2,6,7}
I need the output to be:

```
1 was found 3 times
2 was found 2 times
3 was found 1 time
6 was found 1 time
7 was found 1 time
```

Here is my code. For now I am saving each value in the array to a variable and then loop through the array to check if the value is there then print it out.

```
 int[] nums = { 2, 4, 14, 17, 45, 48, 5, 6, 16, 25, 28, 33, 17, 26, 35, 44, 46, 49, 5, 6, 20, 27, 36, 45, 6, 22, 23, 24, 33, 39, 4, 6, 11, 14, 15, 38, 5, 20, 22, 26, 29, 47, 7, 14, 16, 24, 31, 32 };
            for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
            {
                int s = nums[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < nums.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (s == nums[j])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(s);
                    }
                }

            }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
foreach(var grp in nums.GroupBy(x => x).OrderBy(grp => grp.Key)) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} was found {1} times", grp.Key, grp.Count());
}
```

The `GroupBy` puts all the values into groups using the number itself as the key (via `x => x`). For each unique value we'll have a different group with one or more values in it. The `OrderBy` ensures we report the groups in key-order (via `grp => grp.Key`). Finally, the `Count` tells us how many items are in the group identified by `Key` (the original value, if you recall).

Comment: Now that's what I call awesome!

Comment: It would be nice to explain the OP what you're doing here... nice answer however.

Comment: @MarcGravell very nice! :)

Comment: Thanks, yeah really fast and corrrect answer:o) thank you so much. I still didn`t learn Linq but great stuff..

Comment: An interesting trivia question based on your solution: C# disallows the same simple name to be used to have two different meanings in the same block. Why then is it legal for you to use `grp` both as the loop variable and as the formal parameter of the lambda?

Comment: @Erip I seem to remember you've blogged on this in the past - the scope of grp in the lambda is isolated to the lambda, no?

Answer (score 2):

How about using `.Key` and `.Count` after *Grouping* and *Ordering* them?

```
foreach(var g in nums.GroupBy(x => x).OrderBy(g => g.Key))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} was found {1} times", g.Key, g.Count());
}
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/p054Ci).

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this via [Enumerable.GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx). I recommend looking at the [C# LINQ samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) section on Count and GroupBy for guidance.

In your case, this can be:

```
int[] values = new []{2, 4, 14, 17, 45, 48, 5, 6, 16, 25, 28, 33, 17, 26, 35, 44, 46, 49, 5, 6, 20, 27, 36, 45, 6, 22, 23, 24, 33, 39, 4, 6, 11, 14, 15, 38, 5, 20, 22, 26, 29, 47, 7, 14, 16, 24, 31, 32};

var groups = values.GroupBy(v => v);
foreach(var group in groups)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} was found {1} times", group.Key, group.Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with arrays for pure education? C# offers `Collections` which provide a lot of convenient functionality to address such problems.
The `System.Collections.Dictionary` offers the functionality you are looking for. Adding an item, if it doesn't exist and react, when a key has already been added.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

Dictionary<int,int> dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();
if(!dic.Keys.Contains(key))
   //add key and value
else 
  //get key and add value
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this.